# Tournament Scheduling algorithm based on players score

Tags: algorithm

I am designing a tournament scheduling algorithm but i am facing a problem that 2 same player may match again within the same tournament.
I am not sure are there an official name for this type of tournament, will be appreciate if someone can let me know it name too.

**Requirement:**
 - Winner get 3 points, loser get 0 points, and 1 points each player for draw
 - Player will play against another player who have similar score in each round
 - The tournament end when the Max(score) have only 1 player

**What I tried to do:**
 1. Initial the data in db as follow

```
tournamentId     playerId    score      
1                A           0        
1                B           0       
......  
1                Z           0
```

2. back end select the db by tournamentId=1, order by score and do some shuffling for the same score players.
3. take out players 2 by 2 as the first round schedule.
   using the example in 1. I will have A vs B, C vs D and so on.
4. Update the score after all games done and start from 2 again until Max(score) have 1 player.

**My Problem:**
For my implementation, there will be a possibility that a player will play with the same player again.
For example:
round 1 : A vs B
...
round 4 : if both of them have the same score, they may meet again
How can I modify my algorithm to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have to introduce another condition for this special case. For example, if the players have already played against each other, you pick the most suitable next candidate, which didn't play against one of those players, even if he has a lower score than both. Actually, you can have a look at the [swiss system tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament). I think it is quite close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: The Monrad system is exactly what i am trying to doing, unfortunately it does not talk much on the "condition". My though is at step 3, when every I found out the 2 player have meet before, just switch with the player below it, until I find the next player who have not match before. But i believe it may case some buy, especially when it happened at the end of the list